# Sorting TreeMultiMap based on key and ignore value

Tags: java, sorting, guava

So I have done some research and came to the conclusion that I need to be using a multi tree map, when I used a tree map it allowed me to sort based on the key however I needed multiple values and though that using a tree map would resolve the issue.

My goal is to sort users by their priority, however most users have the default priority which is 0 and one overrides the others (Which is why I need a multimap). However I'm failing to figure out how to construct a TreeMultiMap.

I've never really done any work with comparators which is my main issue right now. I was hoping that someone can point me in the right direction, or in a completely one which allows me to resolve the issue.

Please note that `TreeMap<Integer, List<Entry>>` did come to mind but I would rather not use that as it looks messy and I'm sure there is better and easier ways of implementing what I need.

Thanks

Comment: I added section about the code that I had but I never figured out how to create a TreeMultiMap without it erroring

Comment: [`TreeMultimap.create()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/TreeMultimap.html#create%28%29): *Creates an empty TreeMultimap ordered by the natural ordering of its keys and values.* That was easy enough. --- Note that for `TreeMultimap` *"keys **and values** are ordered"*. If you don't want ordering of values, then this is not the right class for you. A `TreeMap<Integer, List<Entry>>` will order keys, but values are in insertion order, so that may be the right answer, if that's how you want it to function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So with the information that Xaerxess provided, I decided to look into other map and implementations that are provided by Guava but found a way to create a sorted multimap based on a treemap.

Then I used a reverse order comparator, which allowed me to order the values, how I needed them. Thanks to everyone else, who commented with information as it was very helpful.

The code that I ended up using was as follows:

```
Multimap<Integer, Entry> sortedMap = Multimaps.newListMultimap(new TreeMap<>(Collections.reverseOrder()), Lists::newArrayList);
```

Answer (score 1):

Guava's [`Multimap` implementations](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#implementations-1) does not have public constructors, hence the problem with "erroring" - you should use static methods (namely `create` in each implementation) to construct an instance of the multimap. You're probably interested in [`TreeMultimap.create()`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/TreeMultimap.html#create()) (not no capital "m" in "map"), which creates [`SortedSetMultimap`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/SortedSetMultimap.html) and is roughly an equivalent to `TreeMap<K, TreeSet<V>>`. Eg.:

```
SortedSetMultimap<Integer, String> multimap = TreeMultimap.create();
multimap.put(0, "zero");
multimap.put(0, "nought");
multimap.put(1, "one");
System.out.println(multimap);
// prints: {0=[nought, zero], 1=[one]}
```

On the other hand, if you don't want to sort values (or can't), you can use custom multimap, which can be created using [`MultimapBuilder`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/MultimapBuilder.html):

```
ListMultimap<Integer, Entry> multimap = 
    MultimapBuilder.treeKeys().arrayListValues().build();
```